# Code copied with color formatting from Visual Studio to Word stops working after copying certain size of text

Tags: visual-studio, ms-word, formatting

I have installed `visual studio 2022` and `MS office 2016` on my PC with Visual studio color theme `blue`. I can copy c# code from visual studio to Word with color formatting only for certain length of text  approx 10,100 characters. After that it loose `color formatting` when pasted on word. I want to know is there any setting in visual studio or Word that is causing this issue?

[image]

Comment: I’m guessing it’s not expecting you to do that much so that is dropped

Comment: Yes, I think so, that's why I want to know if there is any setting to increase the size of that limit in Visualstudio or word

Comment: This is not a programming question as such and is therefore off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word and Visual Studio should be asked on an appropriate user forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under `Options` > `Text Editor` > `Advanced`, the setting `"Copy rich text on copy/cut"` has a `Max length` sub-setting which you can increase to address this.